# Supremum of a set and equivalence class

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

In my textbook we got the following question:

> Consider the order relationship ⊆ over P (A), with A = {1, 2, 3, 4,
>   5}. What is the supremum of {{1}, {3, 4}}?

My thought process is to find the supremum of each subset so the supremum of {1} and {3,4} which are (I think) 1 and 4. So my solution would be {1,4}. But this isn't the correct answer it seems.

Another question I don't seem to understand is:

> Let S = {a, A, b, B, c, C} a collection of letters, and x ∼ y means
>   that x and y are both vowels are or both consonants. Which of the
>   following sets is an equivalence class for ∼?
>   1. {a, A} 
>   2. {a, b, c} 
>   3. {a, A, b, B} 
>   4. {b, B}

I thought the equivalence class would always be given for a certain term, so for instance [A], but in this case they don't?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the relationship $\subseteq $, $m$ is $\mathbf{upper \,bound}$ of $T$ definition:
$$\forall x\in T, x\subseteq m$$

$m_0$ is $\mathbf{supremum}$ of $T$ definition:
$$\forall m\,is\,upper\,bound\,of\,T, m_0\subseteq m$$

So the supremum of $\{\{1\},\{3,4\}\}$ is $\{1,3,4\}$.
Similarly, the infimum of $\{\{1\},\{3,4\}\}$ is $\varnothing$.

(It’s the first day I use English to write an answer, if there are any wrong expression, please tell me, I am very appreciated.)

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're looking for the least upper bound of a set of sets, that is, the "minimum" set that contains both sets in your set. Among the subsets of $A$ that contain both, the minimum is $\{1,3,4\}$.
2. It's $\{a,A\}$, the class of vowels. 2 and 3 cannot be, because they contain vowels and consonants. 4 cannot be because it does not contain all consonants.

Comment: Appreciate it lots! Does the first question also have an infimum?

As for question two, in case it was {b, B, c, C} would that also be a possible answer? And {b, c} wouldn't be an answer since the capital letters aren't included in the set?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @LLScheme Sorry, missed the first part. The infimum is the empty set, which is the only set contained in both your sets.